# Titlesec not showing bookmarks in right hierarchy and not correctly typeseted in ToC for new classes

Tags: luatex, titlesec, bookmarks

I'm creating new classes with `titlesec` package to work in this hierarchy:

> PART
>     - Prechap
>     -- Presec
>     --- Presubsec

I implemented them as seen in the MWE below. When I compiled the file with `LuaLaTeX` the hierarchy is not respected and they seem to have the same level. The figure shows in the right what I have and what I wish I have in the left.

[image: Right: what I have. Left: what I wish I have.]

Also, in the Table of Contents, the Part is not typeset in small caps. How do I get the hierarchy level as shown above with the classes I have made?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[loadonly]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{draft}

\titleclass{\part}[-1]{page}

% Changes in part name appearence
\titleformat{\part}% command
    [block]% shape
    {\centering\fontsize{30pt}{30pt}\selectfont}% format
    {}% label
    {0 cm}% sep
    {\thispagestyle{empty}}% before-code
    []% after-code

% Changes spaces in between part
\titlespacing{\part}{0 pt}{.4\textheight}{0 cm}

% Add part to toc
\titlecontents{part}[0em]{\Large\bfseries\scshape}{}{}{\hfill\contentspage}[]

% Create prechap class
\titleclass{\prechap}{top}[\part]
\newcounter{prechap}

% Formats prechap entry
\titleformat{\prechap}% command
    [block]% shape
    {\centering\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}\selectfont}% format
    {}% label
    {0 cm}% sep
    {\uppercase}% before-code
    [\thispagestyle{empty}]% after-code

% Changes spaces in between prechap
\titlespacing{\prechap}{0 cm}{1 cm}{1 cm}

% Add prechaps to toc
\titlecontents{prechap}[0em]{\bfseries}{}{}{\hfill\contentspage}[]

% Create presec class
\titleclass{\presec}{straight}[\prechap]
\newcounter{presec}

% Formats presec entry
\titleformat{\presec}% command
    [hang]% shape
    {\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}% format
    {}% label
    {0 cm}% sep
    {\bfseries}% before-code
    []% after-code

% Changes spaces in between presec
\titlespacing{\presec}{0 cm}{1 cm}{.2 cm}

% Add presecs to toc
\titlecontents{presec}[1em]{\scshape}{}{}{\hfill\contentspage}[]

% Create presubsec class
\titleclass{\presubsec}{straight}[\presec]
\newcounter{presubsec}

% Formats presubsec entry
\titleformat{\presubsec}% command
    [hang]% shape
    {\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}% format
    {}% label
    {0 cm}% sep
    {\itshape}% before-code
    []% after-code

% Changes spaces in between presubsec
\titlespacing{\presubsec}{0 cm}{1 cm}{.2 cm}

% Add presubsecs to toc
\titlecontents{presubsec}[2em]{\itshape}{}{}{\hfill\normalfont\contentspage}[]

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \prechap{Preface}
    \lipsum[1]

    \prechap{Prelude}
    \lipsum[2]

    \presec{Section one}
    \lipsum[3]

    \presubsec{Subsection one}
    \lipsum[4]

    \presubsec{Subsection two}
    \lipsum[5]

    \part{Part One}

    \lipsum[6]

    \prechap{Prechap One}
    \lipsum[7]

    \presec{Section Two}
    \lipsum[8]

    \presubsec{Subsection Three}
    \lipsum[9]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding small caps: PDF does not allow a lot of formatting for outline items. You can only set a color and whether the text should be bold or italic. There is no option to turn the text into (real) small caps

Comment: The small caps it's not in the bookmarks but in the ToC page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `hyperref` adds entries to the bookmarks, it takes the level information from commands of the form `\toclevel@<name>`, where `<name>` is the name of the text division. For the book class those are

```
\def\toclevel@part{-1}
\def\toclevel@chapter{0}
\def\toclevel@section{1}
```

and so on.

For your new division types `prechap`, `presec` and `presubsec` those commands are not defined, which `hyperref` warns you about in the log:

```
Package hyperref Warning: bookmark level for unknown prechap defaults to 0.
Package hyperref Warning: bookmark level for unknown presec defaults to 0.
Package hyperref Warning: bookmark level for unknown presubsec defaults to 0.
```

As all levels get a new default level of 0, the bookmarks in your PDF file appear "flat". The solution is simply to add the following lines to your document's preamble to make `hyperref` aware what levels you want your new divisions to correspond to:

```
\makeatletter
\def\toclevel@prechap{0}
\def\toclevel@presec{1}
\def\toclevel@presubsec{2}
\makeatother
```

Now the bookmarks are nested as expected.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem.